# Why is there an energy difference of $\hbar$ between spin up and spin down?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-spin, hamiltonian

In Griffith's *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* he describes the operators related to spin-$1/2$ particles in chapter 4. One of those operators is
$$
\hat{S}_z=\frac{\hbar}{2}\hat{\sigma}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right],
$$
whose eigenvectors represent 'spin up' and 'spin down'. Thus, the energy difference between spin up and spin down is $\hbar$. What I do not understand is that this does not take into account any external factors (such as external fields, interaction with other particles, etc.). So my question is, where does this energy difference come from? What exactly is the difference between 'spin up' and 'spin down' when we do not consider any external factors?

Comment: Note that $\hbar$ has units of angular momentum, not units of energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical Hamiltonian that gives rise to the energy difference between these spin states is
$$H=-\gamma {\bf S}\cdot {\bf B}$$
where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio and we coupled the spin to a magnetic field. If we let the field be constant $B$ and point only in the $z$ direction, we can find a hamiltonian where the energy difference is in actual energy units and the eigenstates have a difference in energy of $\hbar\gamma B$.

So in short, you are right. If we don’t couple the spin to anything, these states have the same energy. Griffiths is taking a shortcut here and should’ve said that they differ in spin or angular momentum by $\hbar$.

Sidenote: the equation I quoted is in Griffiths 4.158 (3rd Ed.)

Answer (score 6):

> Thus, the energy difference between spin up and spin down is $\hbar$.

No, $\hbar$ is not the *energy* difference, because
$\hbar$ has the dimension of energy$\cdot$time
(or equivalently: angular momentum).
Instead, the *angular momentum* difference between spin up and spin down is $\hbar$.
(See [Electron spin](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/spin.html).)

> What I do not understand is that this does not take into account any external factors
> (such as external fields, interaction with other particles, etc.).

Actually the spin-up state ($+\hbar/2$) and the spin-down state ($-\hbar/2$)
do have different energies when the electron is an external magnetic field.
The energy difference  between these two states is
$$\Delta E=2\mu_B B$$
where $B$ is the external magnetic field, and $\mu_B$ is a constant
(called the Bohr magneton).